# Unittesting Python class

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-unittest

```
class Car:
 def __init__(self):
     self.__engine_size = 2.0
     self.__colour = str
 @property # getter
 def engine_size(self):
     return self.__engine_size
 @property # getter
 def colour(self):
     return self.__colour
 @colour.setter
 def colour(self, value):
     self.__colour = value
 def start(self):
     return 'Engine started!!....ggggrrrrrr'
 def stop(self):
     return 'Engine stopped!!...'
```

Hey guys, trying to perform a test on this piece of code but can't think of ways. See bellow what I did and suggest other ways if known.

```
import unittest

from car import __init__

class TestCarMethods(unittest.TestCase):

    # case assertion no1
    '''

    '''

    def test_car_colour(self):

        # arrange
        __engine_size = 3.2
        __colour = 'red'

        # act
        result = ('red')

        # assert
        self.assertEqual(result, 'red')



       if __name__ == '__main__':
         unittest.main()
```

Comment: Don't use a property if the getter/setters just provide unrestricted or unmodified access to the underlying attribute; just use the attribute directly.

Comment: Good point! I get stuck with start - stop

Comment: tests come out naturally by  defining *what should it do*  , but not true when you try saying *how does it do*.   for your piece of code . valid test would be the return values of start/stop, exception checking can be addwed too.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create and work with an instance of your class.

```
class TestCarMethods(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.car = Car()

    def test_car_color(self):
        self.assertEqual(self.car.color, 'red')  # If the default is, in fact, red

    def test_set_color(self):
        self.car.color = 'blue'

        self.assertEqual(self.car.color, 'blue')

    def test_start(self):
        self.assertEqual(self.car.start(), 'Engine started!!....ggggrrrrrr')
```

Comment: Appreciated, and makes a lot of sense setting up,  I get blocked in trying to perform a test on start / stop.

Comment: See update; it's just a matter of calling the method and checking what it returns.

Comment: Gosh, I think I need a break :))) thanks man. for a weird reason I was complicating it thinking that the functions start/ stop is called after color is set .....